# Nested RDFa with meta tags, without div/span?

Tags: html, meta-tags, rich-snippets, rdfa

Is it possible to add rich snippets with RDFa in meta tags, without `div`/`span` elements?

For example: I have an `Event` wrapper and need to specify the `location`, but can't use `div` or `span` because that will mess up with the frontend styles.

I want to add something like this:

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Event">

  <!-- that will not work -->
  <meta property="name:location" typeof="Place" content="Example location name">
  <meta property="address:location" typeof="Place" content="Example location address">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the RDFa processing rules don't care about the actual HTML elements, it just cares about the attributes in those elements. For example, `p`, `a`, `span` and `div` are all the same as far as RDFa is concerned.

Naturally, you still need to make sure that your HTML is valid, but that's the only constraint. You snippet above (using meta nested inside a `div`) would be correct from an RDFa standpoint and would lead to data being extracted. They only restriction you have with meta and link is that you cannot nested other elements inside them.

Note, however, that the point of RDFa is to use the existing "visual" markup as possible, in the sense that if you have the location already displayed in the form of `div`/`span` or `p` elements, then you should try to add RDFa to those.

That said, it's ok to use meta/link inside the body in HTML5 if you don't have that data already displayed, or if it's too cumbersome to add RDFa to it.